# Request fresh value from LiveData

Tags: android, location, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I try to get user (gps) location and use that in parameter of api request.

I have implemented `LocationLiveData`, which is also used in other places of the app when I need user location.

The api request is done inside the `housesRepository`.

My current problem is that when I call view model `loadHousesNearby()` second this, LocationLiveData returns cached location data. It is not fetching fresh location from FusedLocationProviderClient.

How should I force `LocationLiveData` to get completely new location and not return the cached one?

**LocationLiveData**

```
public class LocationLiveData extends LiveData<Location> {
    private final Context context;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;

    public LocationLiveData(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActive() {
        super.onActive();
        FusedLocationProviderClient locationProviderClient = getFusedLocationProviderClient();
        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        Looper looper = Looper.myLooper();
        locationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, looper);
    }

    private FusedLocationProviderClient getFusedLocationProviderClient() {
        if (fusedLocationProviderClient == null) {
            fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context);
        }
        return fusedLocationProviderClient;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onInactive() {
        if (fusedLocationProviderClient != null) {
            fusedLocationProviderClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback);
        }
    }

    private LocationCallback locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
            setValue(locationResult.getLastLocation());
        }
    };
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class MyModel extends ViewModel {  

    private final LocationLiveData locationLiveData;
    private final MediatorLiveData<House> houses;

    ...

    public void loadHousesNearby() {
      houses.addSource(locationLiveData, location -> {
                    houses.removeSource(locationLiveData);
                    houses.addSource(
                            housesRepository.getHousesNearby(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())),
                            housesResp -> {
                                houses.setValue(housesResp);
                            }
                    );
                }
        );

    }
}
```

Comment: I think I had a similar issue, I can see you have location updates on, do you need constant location updates while the LiveData is active?

Comment: I use the same LocationLiveData on other places of the app where I need constant location updates. With the above example, the location update is on only short period of time as there is no subscriber set other than on the loadHousesNearby() (which is removed after I get the data).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it's due to the fact that you only get the fresh location in `onActive` or `onChanged`, and I couldn't find any way to trigger `onActive` manually. I will show you my implementation, I think it may help. My goal was to get the location update once, so not to waste the network. So I have a method in my LiveData extending class that I use:

```
public class BoundLocationManager extends LiveData<Location> {

private static BoundLocationManager instance;
private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

public static BoundLocationManager getInstance(Context appContext, LocationRequest locationRequest) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new BoundLocationManager(appContext, locationRequest);
    }
    return instance;
}

private BoundLocationManager(final Context appContext, LocationRequest locationRequest) {
    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(appContext);
    mLocationRequest = locationRequest;
    mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful() && task.getResult() != null) {
                setValue(task.getResult());
            } else {
                mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, null);
            }
        }
    });

}

LocationCallback mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
        for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
            if (location != null)
                setValue(location);
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onInactive() {
    super.onInactive();
    if (mLocationCallback != null)
        mFusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback);
}


}
```

Then in my activity on fragment I create a method:

```
private void getLocationUpdates() {
        BoundLocationManager.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), mLocationRequest).observe(this, new Observer<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable Location location) {
                if (location != null) {
                  // use the location
                    BoundLocationManager.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), mLocationRequest).removeObserver(this);
                } else
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Unable to establish your location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

And then I just use it wherever:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
    else {
        getLocationUpdates();
    }
}
```

The only reason I am removing observers in `onChanged` is that I only want one update. You don't have to make the class singleton, and certainly, you can improve it from the architecture standpoint, you can also find some comments on this code [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/189987/getting-location-using-livedata-and-fusedlocationproviderclient). I hope you can find it useful to your case.

Comment: Thanks @LieForBananas Unfortunately I have not had change to try your example, but I think it looks like it is not solving my problem? LiveData caches internally the last value, and your are always getting the initial location result.

On your example, your are starting location updates on BoundLocationManager  constructor, but how to fetch new location afterwards?

Comment: @devha I have just checked my application and the call to `getLocationUpdates` returns a fresh forecast (I have a weather app). Because I had the same problem, everytime activity is reloaded LiveData returns cached value, but if a user explicitly presses the refresh button, then a fresh value is fetched. I believe that a fresh value can only be fetched from `onActive` and `onChanged`, I coudn't find a way to invoke `onActive`, so in my case everytime `getLocationUpdates` is called `onChanged` is called too, and the fresh data is received, it's then up to you to remove observers where you want.

Comment: My case is a bit different, I store the values in Room because I want them to survive if the app is completely destroyed. I first verify whether Room has any values and if not, or if a user presses refresh, I fetch new ones. Sorry about talking about my case so much, I hope it can help you, if not, I'm happy to assist further as much as I can.